# How can I compare two hours in java?

Tags: java, android, time, datetime-comparison

I want to calculate restaurant's opened hours. I have two string, for example:

```
String start_hour = "09:00";
String end_hour = "18:00";
```

And current hour for example:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    String current_hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

I calculate open hours with this method:

    public boolean isRestaurantOpenNow() {
            try {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                String current_hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                String st_hour = "09:00";
                String en_hour = "18:00";
                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Date sth = null;
                sth = format.parse(st_hour);
                Date enh = format.parse(en_hour);
                Date nowh = format.parse(current_hour );
                if (nowh != null) {
                    if (nowh.before(enh) && nowh.after(sth)) {
                        // restaurant is open
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // restaurant is close
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ParseException ignored) {
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But I have some problem with that. This method working wrong when start_hour is "13:00" and end_hour "05:00". Because 05:00 hour from next day. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
nowh.before(enh) && nowh.after(sth)
```

use

```
nowh.before(enh) && nowh.after(sth) && sth.before(enh)
|| enh.before(sth) && !(nowh.before(enh) && nowh.after(sth))
```

Apart from that I think Calendar class is supposed to be used differently I assume...

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
public boolean isRestaurantOpenNow() {
    LocalTime startHour = LocalTime.parse("13:00");
    LocalTime endHour = LocalTime.parse("05:00");

    LocalTime currentHour = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (startHour.isBefore(endHour)) { // Both are on the same day
        return currentHour.isAfter(startHour) && currentHour.isBefore(endHour);
    } else { // end is on the next day
        return currentHour.isBefore(endHour) || currentHour.isAfter(startHour) ;
    }
}
```

Trying it just now (21:20 in my time zone):

```
    System.out.println(isRestaurantOpenNow());
```

Output was:

> true

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.